# Probability - calculate first cell that isn't empty while other cells before have no balls in it

Tags: probability

> Let  be some natural number. There are  cells numbered by
> 1,...,. Throwing  balls into cells randomly and independently (a cell
> can contain more than one ball). Let  be the number of the first
> non-empty cell. For example, if =3 then cells 1 and 2 are empty and
> in the cell 3 There is at least one ball.
>
> For each =1,..., , calculate Pr[≥] .

Solution attempt:

To calculate Pr[≥], we need to find the probability that all the first −1 cells are empty.

The probability that a ball lands in a specific cell is 1/, since there are  equally likely cells that a ball can land in. Therefore, the probability that a ball does not land in a specific cell is (1−1/).

To find the probability that all −1 cells are empty, we need to multiply the probability that each of the −1 balls lands in an empty cell. Since the balls are thrown randomly and independently, the probability that a ball lands in an empty cell is (1−1/) raised to the power of −1. Therefore, the probability that all the first −1 cells are empty is (1−1/)^(−1).

Then, Pr[≥] is the probability that the first non-empty cell occurs at position  or greater, which is the complement of the probability that the first non-empty cell occurs in the first −1 cells. So, we can calculate Pr[≥] as follows:

Pr[≥] = 1 - Pr[<] = 1 - (1−1/)^(−1)

Therefore, for each =1,...,, the probability Pr[≥] is given by 1 - (1−1/)^(−1).

Is the answer correct?

Comment: I think not.  Instead, I would look at the probability that all the balls are in cells $j,j+1,\ldots,n-1,n$ by looking at the probability the first ball is and then use the independence of the balls

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would help to look at a simple example.  Let $n = 3$.  We are guaranteed that all of the balls will land in at least one of the bins.  The probability that a ball does not land in the first bin is $1 - 1/3 = 2/3$.  Hence, the probability that all three balls do not land in the first bin is $(2/3)^3$.  Similarly, the probability that a ball does not land in the first two bins is $1 - 2/3 = 1/3$, so the probability that all three balls do not land in the first two bins or, equivalently, that all three balls land in the third bin is $(1/3)^3$.

Now suppose that there are $n$ bins.  The probability that a ball does not land in the first $j - 1$ bins is
$$\frac{n - (j - 1)}{n} = \frac{n + 1 - j}{n}$$
Hence, the probability that none of the balls land in the first $j - 1$ bins is
$$\left(\frac{n + 1 - j}{n}\right)^n$$

Note that when $j = 1$, this reduces to $1$, as it must since every ball must land in at least one of the bins.  When $j = n$, we obtain $(1/n)^n$, which is the probability that the first $n - 1$ bins are empty or, equivalently, that all of the balls land in the last bin.

Hence,
$$\Pr(Z \geq j) = \left(\frac{n + 1 - j}{n}\right)^n$$

Comment: So for $Pr[ = ] = (1/)^{-1} * ((-+1)/)$?

Comment: To find $\Pr(Z = j)$, we must ensure that the first $j - 1$ bins are empty, while the first $j$ bins are not empty.  Thus, $\Pr(Z = j) = \Pr(Z \geq j) - \Pr(Z \geq j + 1) = \left(\frac{n + 1 - j}{n}\right)^n - \left(\frac{n - j}{n}\right)^n$.